# How to access Host devices on Windows 7 VM (Hyper V)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am running Windows 7 with XP mode as a VM on a Windows 11 Host. How do I get the Windows 7 VM and XP Mode to access the Windows 11 Host devices?

Note* Enhanced Session Mode (ESM) IS NOT supported on Windows 7. the option is greyed out, which is why i am looking for other alternatives to access hot devices; printers, com, etc*

Comment: If you cannot get Enhanced Session mode to run (can be a function of the Hyper-V guest and also using a Generation 2 Guest), then you probably need a different VM App than Hyper-V.  Consider VMware Workstation (good support for Windows 7)

Comment: Enhanced Session requires Windows 8.1.  If you set up remote desktop on your Win7 VM and from Win11 connect with that you can access the Win11 drives, printers, etc, just check off the boxes you need in the Remote desktop settings.